# How to split each character in a column to their own column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a column of words:

```
       a
0   bear
1    fox
2   wolf
3  mouse
```

that I need to split into multiple columns such that the output would be

```
   0  1  2    3    4
0  b  e  a    r  NaN
1  f  o  x  NaN  NaN
2  w  o  l    f  NaN
3  m  o  u    s    e
```

please consider that each row does not have the same number of characters

np.asarray returns me with a value error: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: I edited the question to add a correct DataFrame format, please confirm that it is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a regex (and lookarounds) and expand it:

```
out = df['a'].str.split(r'(?<=.)(?=.)', expand=True)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CTDwwi/1) for the `split`.

---

Alternatively, use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to get each character, and reshape with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = (df['a'].str.extractall('(.)')[0]
       .unstack('match')
       .rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2    3    4
0  b  e  a    r  NaN
1  f  o  x  NaN  NaN
2  w  o  l    f  NaN
3  m  o  u    s    e
```

Comment: @sammywemmy of course, silly me! I just replaced the first approach ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assuming 'a' is a pandas Series
a = pd.Series(['bear', 'fox', 'wolf', 'mouse'])

# Splitting the characters and stacking them as columns
split_chars = a.str.split('', expand=True).drop(0, axis=1)

# Creating 'ao' column by joining the characters
ao = a.str.cat(sep='')

# Printing the results
print(split_chars)
print(ao)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would use `str.cat` here. It makes no sense. Has this answer been AI-generated?

Comment: This line concatenates all the strings in Series 'a' together into a single string, without any separator in between. The result is stored in the variable 'ao'.

Comment: You can use lambda function converts each word into a list of characters and pads it with NaN values to match the maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.concat(list(df['a'].map(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(x)))),
          axis=1).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2    3    4
0  b  e  a    r  NaN
1  f  o  x  NaN  NaN
2  w  o  l    f  NaN
3  m  o  u    s    e
```